# Can another creature move through the Echo Knight fighter's Manifest Echo's space?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, echo-knight

I would like to know if another creature, hostile or not, can move through the space occupied by an Echo, created by the Manifest Echo ability of an Echo Knight?

Per the rules for Manifest Echo, an Echo "...occupies its space."  But it is also described as an "image".

This question relates directly to, "[Can an Echo Knight fighter's Manifest Echo move through another creature's space?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/183927/can-an-echo-knight-fighters-manifest-echo-move-through-another-creatures-space)"

Comment: Honestly, you don't need those crawford tweets. If someone wants to use them in an answer, that's up to them, but it doesn't really help us in our determination and sits better in the answers section.

Comment: @NautArch Should I remove the tweet reference?  If someone answers that an Echo is not an object, does it matter?

Comment: I personally think you should - others may not agree :) But if someone answers that it's not an object, that's a reasonable statement if they can support it. Crawford's statement on it really is neither here nor there for some people. FOr others, it is important, but it isn't a 100% always-on rule.

Comment: @Imaginary I think the quote just confuses the question. Personally, I have issues with the implication that spell or supernatural effects that occupy space should be treated as objects when the rules text doesn't explicitly say that -- that's how you get people trying to *disintegrate* a *guardian of faith* or break a *spiritual weapon* by hitting it with a hammer.

Answer (score 3):

### It is unclear, so the table needs to decide

Unfortunately, this mechanic of the Echo Knight is incredibly unclear as to how to adjudicate these things for moving it. I have reviewed other potential similar mechanic like *spiritual weapon* or *telekinesis*, but none of those have the same properties of the Echo Knight.

Which leaves us with a giant shrug as to what to do. In these cases, it comes down to the player talking to the DM about what they feel is fair, reasonable, and fun. There is no 'wrong' answer here, but you should think about the potential consequences for each decision.

Looking at how this might affect gameplay of movement, positioning, and battlefield control, it's important to think about the edge cases - but you're not going to cover them all. And that's okay! When they come up, discuss together and be reasonable. If the DM provides an unhappy result, table the argument until after the game and discuss why you didn't like it and what you think a good compromise could be.

#### Prepare in advance

Given the lack of clarity about this subclass in general, if a player is considering choosing it then they should discuss these issues with the DM prior to playing. Making sure everyone understands the gray areas, what ambiguities need to be agreed on, and that judgments may come up that require an immediate ruling will go a long way to to mitigating any unhappiness and setting the expectation that this subclass is a little loosey goosey.