# Can Echo Knight fighter's Manifest Echo's be forcibly moved?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, echo-knight

I would like to know if an Echo, created by the Manifest Echo ability of an Echo Knight, can be forcibly moved by things else other than the Knight?

Per the rules for Manifest Echo, an Echo "...occupies its space."  But it is also described as an "image".  It is also worth noting that [per a tweet by Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/1240669629661380609), an Echo itself is not considered a creature, and instead considered an "object".

Possible methods of forced movement include: shoving, spells like telekinesis, or class abilities.  Which if any of these might apply to an Echo if it considered an object?  And is the echo considered to have a 'weight' for spells like telekinesis?

Or is an Echo more like the "Spiritual Weapon" or similar spells?

This question relates directly to, "[Can another creature move through the Echo Knight fighter's Manifest Echo's space?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/183931/can-another-creature-move-through-echo-knight-fighters-manifest-echos-space)"

Also related, "[Is an Echo Knight fighter's “echo” a tangible object, for the purpose of physical interaction?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169414/is-an-echo-knight-fighters-echo-a-tangible-object-for-the-purpose-of-physica)"

Answer (score 4):

### It is unclear, so the table needs to decide

Unfortunately, this mechanic of the Echo Knight is incredibly unclear as to how to adjudicate these things for moving it. I have reviewed other potential similar mechanic like *spiritual weapon* or *telekinesis*, but none of those have the same properties of the Echo Knight.

Which leaves us with a giant shrug as to what to do. In these cases, it comes down to the player talking to the DM about what they feel is fair, reasonable, and fun. There is no 'wrong' answer here, but you should think about the potential consequences for each decision.

Looking at how this might affect gameplay of movement, positioning, and battlefield control, it's important to think about the edge cases - but you're not going to cover them all. And that's okay! When they come up, discuss together and be reasonable. If the DM provides an unhappy result, table the argument until after the game and discuss why you didn't like it and what you think a good compromise could be.

#### Prepare in advance

Given the lack of clarity about this subclass in general, if a player is considering choosing it then they should discuss these issues with the DM prior to playing. Making sure everyone understands the gray areas, what ambiguities need to be agreed on, and that judgments may come up that require an immediate ruling will go a long way to to mitigating any unhappiness and setting the expectation that this subclass is a little loosey goosey.

Comment: Can you at least put some effort into these copy pasted answers, I understand the Echo Knight can be very ambiguous but at least show rulings that might be relevant to the question instead of a lecture on DM rulings.

Comment: @Pepijn What more are you looking for? I'm not sure what else to add. I don't believe there are relevant rulings - that's what I tried to find. This is a new mechanic.